# django-autocomplete-light showing "This field is required" error If I try to create a new entry

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I have a form where I have used django-autocomplete.

**If the entry is present it should autocomplete the entry , and if the entry is not present
already it should allow me to create a new entry through the same form.**

But When I tried to submit the form with a new entry in those autocomplete fields like song_name
I got:

```
"This field is required." Error.
```

It did not create the post variable "song_name" only "song_name-autocomplete" is present.

The form has:

```
song_name
song_language
album_name
album_artist
album_pub_year
author_name
```

Here is the post data:

```
song_name-autocomplete:asdfghjkl
song_language:hindi
album_name-autocomplete:sdfghjkl
album_artist-autocomplete:sdfghjl
album_pub_year:2003
author_name:prajjwal1
```